# Ruby coding: List out all factors of numbers from 1-100

Tags: ruby, factors

Write a function that prints out all the factors for each of the numbers 1 through 100.

Really amateur coder but here's my attempt so far.

```
def factors_numbers(n1,n2)
  (n1..n2).each do |n|
    factors = []
    factors << 1 ##every number has a factor of 1
    factors << n ##every number is a factor of itself
    i = 1
    while i < n 
        new_number = n % (n-i) 
        if new_number == 0 #if 0, divisible and that means two numbers are factors
            factors << new_number
            factors << (n-i)
        end
        i += 1
    end
    return factors
  end
end
```

Comment: 1. You are adding new_number to factors when it is zero. That way all numbers will show to have a factor of zero. 2. Your question doesn't require returning the factors, just printing them out. Use some puts statements to achieve that. If you need to return, use a Hash.

Comment: If `n1 = 3` and `n2 = 5`, by suggesting you "return a hash", @Chandranshu means return `{3=>[1,3], 4=>[1,2,4], 5=>[1,5]}`.

Comment: What is the question? Does it not work or do you want us to do a code review? If it's the later then the "question" needs to be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. And, is this homework or a tutorial? In either case, are you asking for help for something you should be doing yourself?

Comment: @linsaurus - You have multiple correct answers below. They all use different constructs and have their own advantages. Please read and understand all of them. One way to improve your understanding would be to compare your code to my code and then chipping away at my code to arrive at the code from Peter Alfvin and then to the code from James Adam. And don't forget to accept an answer so that this question shows up as solved.

Comment: @Chandranshu! thank you, your help is much appreciated! thanks everyone else for their help too. @the Tin Man- it's a problem I found in one of the ruby tutorials. couldn't figure it out myself so thought I could get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an improved version of your code:

```
def factors_numbers(n1,n2)
  all_factors = {}
  (n1..n2).each do |n|
    factors = []
    (1..Math.sqrt(n).floor).each do |i|
      remainder = n % i
      if remainder == 0 #if 0, divisible and that means two numbers are factors
        factors << i
        factors << n/i
      end
    end
    factors = factors.sort.uniq
    puts "Factors of #{n}: #{factors.join(',')}"
    all_factors[n]=[factors]
  end
  return all_factors
end
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland - No, Math.sqrt is to improve performance. All factors of `n` less than `Math.sqrt(x)` have a counterpart bigger than `Math.sqrt(x)`. It's for this reason that you only need to check up to  the square root of a number to test for primality.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - And my code would happily return 8. I'm iterating on all values from `1` till `Math.sqrt(n)` and not just prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want unique factors? That is, in the range 1-100, should I get the number 1 a hundred times, or only once?

The easiest way to do this is by leveraging the "inject" Enumerable method.

```
def find_all_factors_between(n1,n2)
  (n1..n2).inject([]) do |factors, num|
    factors + (1..num).inject([]) { |arry, test| num % test == 0 ? arry + [test] : arry }
  end
end
```

One final thing to note is that Ruby has implicit returns; that is, as long as the output of the last line of your method is your `factors` variable, you don't have to say `return factors`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(n1..n2).each{|x| print "#{x}: #{(1..x).select{|y| x % y == 0}}\n"}
```

That oughta do it :)

edit: Implemented Cary Swoveland's suggestion

Comment: You don't need to return `y` in your `select` block, just a boolean, so simply `x % y == 0` will do.

Comment: Correct sir!  Saved me a couple characters :)

Comment: James, that would be a big deal at [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: I like your use of `select`. If printing the results is all that is required, you could replace `map` with `each` and print what's inside the block for each `x`.

Answer (score 0):

And my entry would be:

```
def find_all_factors_between(n1, n2)
  factors = -> (n) { (1..n).select {|i| n % i == 0} }
  (n1..n2).each { |n| puts "Factors of #{n}: #{factors.(n).join(', ')}" }
end

find_all_factors_between(1,100)
```

Comment: Within the interpolated string, shouldn't it be `factors(n)` rather than `factors.(n)`?

Comment: @Chandranshu Nope. `factors.(n)` is short for `factors.call(n)`. You need the `call` because it's a `Proc`.

Comment: @Chandranshu, `factors[n]` and `factors.yield(n)` also work.  Here the method `yield` is not to be confused with the keyword of the same name.

Comment: yep, I read the documentation day before yesterday after Peter's reply. Thanks for pointing it out again?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Actually, I didn't know that `factors[n]` would work. Can you point me to any documentation on that?

Comment: For 2.0, all the methods are listed [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Proc.html#method-i-call). `.()` is under `call`; `[]` and `yield` have their own descriptions.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sure enough. Can't imagine the rationale for `prc[]`. Let me know if you happen to know (or have an idea about) what it is.

Comment: Peter, I know nothing more than what it says in the docs, that it sets "the block’s parameters to the values in params using something close to method-calling semantics." (my hyphen). I rather like it.  The one I find odd is `yield`, which surely will cause confusion.  I only learned about these recently.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I found https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4407820#1084230. `[]` makes sense as an efficient alternative to the rejected `()`, but now I don't understand the semantics of the example Matz used to argue against `()`, namely `p = Object.new ; p(15)` ;-)

Comment: I think Matz meant that Ruby wouldn't know if 15 was an argument to the instance `p` of `Object` or to `Kernel#p`. You could think of this in terms of `p = Proc.new {|e| ...}`. ruby-trunk is often interesting, eh?

Comment: Ok, I think I get that. As things stand now, if you have a method `foo` defined on `self` (or any ancestor) and a variable `foo`, then the variable will take precedence over the method in the absence of parentheses, but the parentheses can be used to force a reference to the method. If parentheses were allowed as a means to invoke lambdas, then there's no way to get at the method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you wanted to do it with enumerables, there's always

```
def factor_numbers(rng)
  factors = rng.map do |n|
    (1..Math.sqrt(n).floor)         # search numbers <= square root
      .select { |d| n % d == 0 }    # find factors <= square root
      .flat_map { |x| [x, n / x] }  # combine with factors >= square root
      .sort                         # order from least to greatest
      .uniq                         # remove dupes (basically the square root)
  end

  Hash[rng.zip(factors)]            # rng = keys, factors = values
end

puts factor_numbers(1..100)
```

It's not the most efficient, but my point is just that many of the for/while constructs you'd see in languages like C or JavaScript can be expressed in other ways in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

```
def factor_nums(n1,n2)
    all_factors = {}
    (n1..n2).each do |n|
        factors = []
        (1..n).each do |i|
            remainder = n % i
            factors << i if remainder == 0
        end
        all_factors[n] = factors
    end
return all_factors
end
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.